# PHP Regex Problem:

Tags: php, regex

```
$string1 = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9äöü!&_=\+-]/', ' ', $string4);
```

This Regex shouldn't replace the chars äöü.
In Ruby it worked as expected.
But in PHP it replaces also the ä ö and ü.

Can someone give me a hint how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `u` [pattern modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) (to tell php to treat the regex as a UTF-8 string).

```
'/[^A-Za-z0-9äöü!&_=\+-]/u'
```

Comment: Are you sure those are the exact characters?  That they are not character entities?  Can you show us the source strings that you're not getting to work?

Comment: yes sure: $string4="abcdeför ahügöld ;:";    without the /u it replaces the ö and ü, with the /u it outputs nothing

Comment: It works fine for me here (with or without the `/u`): `var_dump($string1, $string4);` yields: `string(22) "abcdeför ahügöld   " string(22) "abcdeför ahügöld ;:"`.  What version of PHP?  Also, are you saving the file as a UTF-8 file (the PHP source code file)?

Comment: I'm using php 5.3 and the sourcecode is saved in utf-8 format. when i use vardump with /u i get NULL string(19) "abcdeför ahügöld ;:" when i use without u it gives me abcdef r ah g ld string(19) "abcdef r ah g ld " string(19) "abcdeför ahügöld ;:"

Comment: sorry guys, was my fault, had another mistake in my script. the regex now works as expected, but still have problems with charset and öäü replacement in different charsets

Answer (score 0):

Unicode support is one of the features promised for **PHP 6**.

**Currently in php5**

- use the [multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) like [mb_ereg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php)
- PHP will interpret '/regex/u' as a UTF-8 string, with preg_match,preg_replace

Comment: that's unicode support for the code itself.  (Unicode variable names, etc).  PHP does have support for dealing with UFT-8 strings at present (although there are a bunch of gotcha's, and the native string functions typically don't work well with it)...

Comment: but there are some function that still supported in php5, check the update.

Comment: the mb functions make problems with the output.

Comment: thats right, you cant trust most of the time it works but sometime you dont know. that why my first line is "Unicode support is one of the features promised for PHP 6." @ndi, have you tried perl instead

Comment: no, i don't know pearl. i go with ruby instead. thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

i think this should work:

```
$string1 = preg_replace('/\[^A-Za-z0-9\pL!&_=\+-]/u', ' ', $string4 );
```

Comment: '/[^\pL]/u' where the L is for "Letters"
Maybe you have to add the other chars as well
This requires PHP > 5.1 (http://de2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php)